# Ajax to Webservice Asmx file returns Xml value but need json value

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, web-services, asp.net-ajax

Simple HTML button in asp.net page when clicks the button the Ajax code pass the call to service page method and return the value but in XML format need it in json

### Ajax Code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#btnSubmit").click(function(){
        txtNameValue = $("#txtName").val();
       alert("button clicked");

        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: serviceURL+"/HelloWorld",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        async: true,
        success:function(response) {

            console.log(response);
        }
        });

    });    
});
```

### Service Page code

```
using System;
using System.Web;
using System.Collections;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Web.Services.Protocols;



/// <summary>
/// Summary description for FirstPageWebService
/// </summary>
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
//[ScriptService]
public class FirstPageWebService : System.Web.Services.WebService {

    public FirstPageWebService () {

        //Uncomment the following line if using designed components 
        //InitializeComponent(); 
    }


    [WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public string HelloWorld() {

        return "Hello World";
    }

}
```

In HTML page when tracks through networks Got this response in XML

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<string xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">Hello World</string>
```

---

[image: For error Image click here]

Comment: `[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]` un comment this line

Comment: no response page with some errors

Comment: What are the errors ?

Comment: need to return json value

Comment: ASMX is a legacy technology, and should not be used for new development. WCF or ASP.NET Web API should be used for all new development of web service clients and servers. One hint: Microsoft has retired the [ASMX Forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/asmxandxml/threads) on MSDN.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **JavaScriptSerializer** in your service method :

```
return new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize("Hello World");
```